# Offline Vector Tile Package Style

Tags: arcgis, arcgis-runtime, vector-tiles, arcgis-runtime-net

Is there currently a way to swap out styles of an offline local Vector Tile Package (.vtpk) without ArcGIS Pro?  I'm open to accomplishing this programatically with the ArcGIS Runtime SDK for .NET (WPF).  The goal is to maintain a single copy instead of two copies of a vector tile package with differing styles.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ArcGIS Runtime** doesn't have support for custom styles with .vtpk files at the moment. Unfortunately you have to use the 2 file approach with different default styles defined for now (release 100.0). That said, we are working to get a proper support for the offline styles to the runtime in next releases.